# PostgreSQL How to get average of sum of certain rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I apologize if the title isn't very apt, but I had a little trouble formulating a concise title. Anyway, I have a table that keeps a log of states a person is in. It looks like:

```
id, login, state, duration, started_at
1, pdiddy, working, 1200, 2018-05-25 08:30:00
2, pdiddy, lunch, 120, 2018-05-25 9:00:00
3, pdiddy, on_call, 65, 2018-05-25 12:30:00
4, pdiddy, available, 1115, 2018-05-25 12:30:00
5, pdiddy, working, 143, 2018-05-25 12:30:00
6, pdiddy, break1, 150, 2018-05-25 12:30:00
7, pdiddy, working, 2400, 2018-05-25 12:30:00
8, pdiddy, break2, 110, 2018-05-25 12:30:00
```

I need to get an average for only labor-related durations on a day-by-day basis for each user. So basically I need to add up the durations for everything other than "lunch", "break1", and "break2" for any given day and get the average for it.

I tried to do this like this, but the problem with this is that it doesn't add up the labor-related logs before averaging. I can't figure out how to do that.

```
SELECT
    log.login,
    AVG(log.duration) FILTER (WHERE log.state NOT IN ('lunch', 'break1', 'break2')) AS "labor_average"
FROM
    log
GROUP BY 1
```

Obviously I don't expect anybody to just do this for me. I just need to be pointed in the right direction. I'm obviously quite a ways from the solution, so I just need a push in the right direction. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Average of what? Duration?

Comment: average of the sum of the durations which are not "lunch", "break1" or "break2"

Comment: sorry about that. I fixed my description. should be a little less nonsensical now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the total sum divided by the number of days:

```
SELECT l.login,
       (SUM(l.duration) FILTER (WHERE l.state NOT IN ('lunch', 'break1', 'break2')) /
        COUNT(DISTINCT date_trunc('day', l.started_at)
       ) AS labor_average
FROM log l
GROUP BY l.login
```

Comment: Should the `COUNT` have the same `FILTER` as `SUM`? Why use `FILTER` at all? Why not simple `WHERE`?

Comment: this result came out almost exactly to what the other response did. I think this is the solution I have to go with though because I don't think I can do subqueries with the tools I'm using unfortunately. Thank you!

Comment: @VladimirBaranov . . . I am guessing there are "work" states on all days with a break.  If there are not, it is not clear whether or not the OP wants to count them.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate sum per login and per day first.

Then calculate average per login.

```
SELECT
    login, AVG(SumDuration) AS AvgDuration
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        login, started_at::date, SUM(duration) AS SumDuration
    FROM log
    WHERE log.state NOT IN ('lunch', 'break1', 'break2')
    GROUP BY login, started_at::date
    ) AS T
GROUP BY login;
```

Comment: Sorry I'm having server timeouts for some reason. Trying to test your answers I will get back to you. Thanks for the responses so far.