# subquery problem - need to get avg of a sum

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables

```
sales table
weekly sales, store, date

store table
store, type, size
```

my sales table has multiple years, multiple stores and multiple types.  I'm trying to get the avg sales by sqft for each store type per year.  I have a sub query that shows the sales by sqft for each store but Im having trouble then rolling it up into my main query to get the avg by type

[image]

Anything jumps out with my final query?

```
SELECT 
    date_part('year', sales.date) AS year, 
    stores.type,
    AVG(sales_by_sqft)
FROM
    (SELECT 
     SUM((sales.weekly_sales)/stores.size) AS sales_by_sqft
    FROM SALES
    INNER JOIN stores ON sales.store = stores.store
    GROUP BY sales.store) AS sq
FROM sales
INNER JOIN stores ON sales.store = stores.store
WHERE date_part('year', date) = 2012
GROUP BY year, stores.type;
```

getting a syntax error on the second FROM statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607651/postgresql-how-to-get-average-of-sum-of-certain-rows

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. AVG doesn't work on money.  Once I changed that data type to integer, it all fell in place

```
SELECT
    year,
    type,
    ROUND(AVG(sales_by_sqft),2)AS avg_sales_by_sqft
FROM 
(SELECT
        date_part('year', sales.date) AS year,
        stores.type,
        sales.store,
        stores.size,
        SUM(sales.weekly_sales) AS total_sales,
        SUM(sales.weekly_sales)/ AVG(stores.size) AS sales_by_sqft
    FROM sales
    INNER JOIN stores ON sales.store = stores.store
    GROUP BY year, stores.type, sales.store, stores.size) AS sq
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,3 DESC;
```